# SQL query to consider the rows from the current table and exclude data present in the other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in a Postgres Database.

```
Table A
{
userid1
userid2
count
}

Table B
{
userid1
userid2
}
```

I am trying to get all the data except the data with the same userid1 and userid2 in Table B. 
The following query gives only two columns but I need the third column in the Table A as well.

```
Select userid1,userid2 from A except (select * from B)
```

Please help me with this issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.userid1 = a.userid1 and b.userid2 = a.userid2
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, since it is a correlated query, won't it affect the performance ?

Comment: @Ranjan . . . It will be fine if you have an index on `b(userid1, userid2)`.